# Класс String (valueof и проверка)

Tags: java, строки

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       String str = String.valueOf(65);
       if(str.equals(str)){
           System.out.println("Меня зовут Ваня");
       }
    }
}
```

Правильно ли я проверил значение которое было целочисленное, а стало строковое (65)? Если у нас сравнивается 1 (строка), значение,  можно ли использовать вот такую конструкцию:

```
String str = String.valueOf(65);

       if(str.equals(str)){
           System.out.println("Меня зовут Ваня");
       }
```

И хотел еще спросить: equals() у нас сравнивает значение строк.
А == сравнивает ссылки на объекты?

Comment: `X.equals(X)` всегда будет  true, если X не null. Что именно Вы хотите проверить этим условием?

Comment: Хочу проверить является ли значение 65 в методе valueOf строкой

Comment: [`String.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)) всегда возвращает строку. Да и Вы присваиваете это значение переменной типа String.

Comment: Может Вы хотите проверить получилась ли правильная строка? Что-то вроде: `"65".equals(str)`

Comment: Проверил, вот так if ("65".equals(str)) и выдало true

Comment: И хотел еще спросить: equals() у нас сравнивает значение строк. А == сравнивает ссылки на объекты?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван да

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выражение:

```
str.equals(str)
```

всегда будет возвращать true, если str не равно null, т.к. строка сравнивается сама с собой.

Если нужно проверить правильная ли получилась строка можете использовать такое условие:

```
if("65".equals(str)) {
....
```

> equals() у нас сравнивает значение строк. А == сравнивает ссылки на объекты?

Да.

Answer (score 4):

`equals` это в принципе метод, который обычно проводит массу проверок:

- обычно сначала проверяется, что сравниваемые объекты не нулевые (потому что даже `null.euals(null) == false`)
- что объекты принадлежат к одному классу
- не являются ли сравниваемые объекты одним и тем же объектом,

  тот самый случай, когда может быть `obj1 == obj2`
- затем уже сравнивается внутреннее значение полей.

В классе `String` метод `equals` после всех проверок на одинаковость классов сравнивает массивы байтов, полученные из строк:

```
@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
public static boolean equals(byte[] value, byte[] other) {
    if (value.length == other.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (value[i] != other[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Но это все верно для хорошо реализованных классов, таких как `String`, идущих с Java "из коробки". Для новых классов, если вы не переопределите этот метод, `equals` будет работать по умолчанию как в родительском классе (скорее всего классе `Object`):

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

И в этом случае будет просто сравнивать ссылки. Имейте в виду такое коварство.